# What kind of file does Microsoft QnA Maker accepts in the knowledge base?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, bots, azure-qna-maker

I recently started creating a bot using QnA maker. I tried feeding it a bunch of pdf files. But it seems like QnA maker is very particular about the format of the files it is being fed. For example: it can not read documents with columns (IEEE format). 
Does anyone know if there is a knowledge base document rules that the QnA maker abide by? 
Also where can I find the source code for the QnA maker so I can customize it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Asking for off-site references is specifically off topic for this site.

Comment: @Prune Help me understand why is this a bad question. If not here then where can I get an answer for my question?

Comment: What don't you understand from reading the "on topic" page?  There's also a reference with a title something like "which site to post on?"

Answer (score 0):

Data must be in faq format or tsv format otherwise file can't feed
 Tsv format like this 
Question   answer  source  metadata
How are you ?    I am fine  file2.pdf